# How can show warnings in Terminal if Console.log is used in React JS project?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, eslint, eslintrc

I want to restrict developers to add console.log in their commits so I want to show warning in React JS running terminal if they have used console.log anywhere is the project.

I want to show warnings like this in the project:

[image]

I'm using Eslint and specified no-console: 2 in the project. But the react app is compiling without any warning when I have console.log.

Comment: It sounds like you want to run ESLint in the CLI in a pre-commit [hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a rule [`no-console`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-console) as

```
no-console: "error"
```

or

```
"no-console": [ "error", { "allow": [""] ]
```

Comment: I've added this and still App is compiling without any warning or error.

Comment: where have you added this

Comment: .eslintrc file, in rules section.